# Define supporting only 1-level menu

Tags: sub-menu

please help.

Is there any way for the theme to define this theme support only 1-level menu only?

I mean is there any hooks, actions, filter so that when user go Admin Panel > Appearance > Menu, editing/adding the menu, they cannot drag and drop to make the sub menu?